# How to implement redash into my website dashboard

Tags: angular, hapi, redash

I am a beginner, and I have been assigned a task to use Redash on my website to manage the charts within the dashboard.im using angular for client side and hapi js for server side. How do I go about it, and where should I start learning using redash?

Making redash to implement in my dashboard